# Exceptions and errors being printed in wrong order

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

Program is used to parse program arguments into geometrical shapes.

- Circle (C): 1 arg [radius]
- Pentagon (P): 1 arg [side]
- Square, Rhombus, Rect (Q): 5 args [a,b,c,d,angleA] (program chooses which
  one to generate based on args)

My issue is with order of printing exceptions/errors in console.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    if (args.length > 0)
    {
        int readerIndex = 0; // currently read argument

        for (char symbol : args[readerIndex++].toCharArray())
        {
            ShapeType type = null; // Enum for C, P or Q.
            int toRead = 0; // How many args should we read.
            int read = 0; // How many we alredy read.

            try
            {
                type = ShapeType.bySymbol(symbol); // C, P or Q.
                toRead = type.getDataFormatSize(); // number of args to read.

                double[] vars = new double[toRead];
                // converting
                for (int i = 0; i < vars.length; ++i)
                {
                    vars[i] = Double.valueOf(args[readerIndex + i]);
                    ++read;
                }
                // This will create and print proper shape for given data.
                System.out.println(ShapeFactory.generateShape(type, vars).toString());
            }
            catch (ShapeSymbolException e) // thrown if letter is not a shape symbol.
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) // when we are out of args.
            {
                System.err.println("Too few arguments to generate " + type.name() + "!");
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e) // When we can't convert to double.
            {
                System.err.println("Could not convert String to double while generating " + type.name() + ". Offender: " + args[readerIndex + read] + " | Dumping arguments: " + Arrays.toString(Arrays.copyOfRange(args, readerIndex, readerIndex + toRead)));
            }
            catch (ShapeGenException e) // When data passed to ShapeFactory cannot generate proper shape from it.
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally
            {
                readerIndex += toRead; // In any case (exception or not) - we will be skipping args that were supposed to be parsed to shape.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now for data inputs:

- C 10

> ```
> CIRCLE (C) | Radius = 10.0
> ```

- CQP 3 2 4 2 4 90 50

> ```
> CIRCLE (C) | Radius = 3.0
> QUADRILATERAL (Q) | RECTANGLE | Side A = 2.0 | Side B = 4.0
> PENTAGON (P) | Side = 50.0
> ```

- CQPPQ 3 2 4 2 4 90 50 w2 2 2 2 2 90

> ```
> CIRCLE (C) | Radius = 3.0
> QUADRILATERAL (Q) | RECTANGLE | Side A = 2.0 | Side B = 4.0
> PENTAGON (P) | Side = 50.0
> Could not convert String to double while generating PENTAGON. Offender: w2 | Dumping arguments: [w2]
> QUADRILATERAL (Q) | SQUARE | Side = 2.0
> ```

The "Could not conver..." part is randomly printed in console. It USUALLY is where it is supposed to be (4th in sequence) but about 1/3 of times it will appear either before or after one of other prints.

I could understand it printing later, but earlier? I can't think of anything.

Why does that happen?

Answer (score 7):

`System.err` and `System.out` are two independent streams - Order is only guaranteed within a single stream. Since both streams are merged into your console in an undefined manner, the order in which text printed to both streams appears can shift around. If you print everything to `System.out`, you will have well-ordered output.